# After Response.Redirect() frm CurrentPage to NewPage in NewTab, CurrentPage is redirecting again to NewPage on clickin othr contrls on CurrentPage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, redirect

I have a page(abc.aspx) on which i have performed a `Response.Redirect()` on button Click to new page(xyz.aspx) in new window tab. The problem is that after `Redirect()`, when i click on other controls on the page it redirects to xyz.aspx page in a new windows tab.

Please Help/Advice

Comment: How is this possible ? Check if any `ids` are clashing with the button `id`.

Comment: @TusharRaj - im able to figure out the issue but not able to resolve it.. the issue was with the Link button's OnClientClick property OnClientClick="document.forms[0].target = '_blank';"
how can i fix this property code

Comment: what this button does ? Is it doing the same thing that your mail button was doing ?Can you provide some `HTML` and `SCRIPT` ?